# Why am I getting an error in apollo client when trying to pass an additional value to queries using @connection directive?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I am having some issues with caching queries when using apollo client and I need to pass additional key to the query other than variables passed to the query.

From the apollo client documentation, i found that we can use @connection directive to pass additional data.

According to the document

> If you execute this query with different values for the $feedKey variable, those feed results are stored separately in the cache, whereas normally they would all be stored in the same list.

Please check the attached image.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Udl.png)

But when I tried to do something simillar it returns me an error saying **variable $feedKey is never used in operation.**

Any idea on what could be the issue here? Thank you

Comment: The same problem and. i've created the issue about this case in the apollo client github: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/11099